# WCF 70-513 Practice Exam doubts

Tags: wcf

**tl;dr**

*For this question, the answer is supposed to be `AB`. `A` I can understand but I can't find any information about a standalone `CreateChannnel` method like it's used in `B`*

*Can anyone explain why answer `B` is considered correct or is it **not** correct and I'm better of ditching these practice exams alltogether?*

---

**Background**

I am trying to learn `WCF` using some practice exams. I have already encountered several questions where I'm not sure that the given answer is the correct one.

The following question, besides the obvious spelling mistakes *(intetface INameService)* is seriously adding to my doubts.

**The question goes like this**

> QUESTION 21
>
> A Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) solution uses the following
>   contracts. (Line numbers are included for reference only.)

```
01 [ServiceContract(CallbackContract=typeof(INameService))]   
02 public interface IGreetingService   
03 {   
04  [OperationContract]   
05  string GetMessage();  
06 }  
07  
08 [ServiceContract]
09 public intetface INameService 
10 { 
11  [OperationContract] 
12  string GetName(); 
13 }
```

> When the client calls GetMessage on the service intetface, the service
>   calls GetName on the client callback. In the client, the class
>   NameService implements the callback contract.The client channel is created as follows:

```
22 InstanceContext callbackContext = new Instance Context(new NameService("client"));  
23  
24  
25 DuplexChannelFactory <IGreetingService> factory = 
    new DuplexChannelFactory<IGreetingServices>(typeof(NameService),binding,address);  
26 IGreetingService greetingService = factory.CreateChannel();
```

> You need to ensure that the senvice callback is processed by the
>   instance of NameService. What are two possible ways to achieve this
>   goal? (Each correct answer presents a complete solution. Choose two.)

**and I can choose from following answers**

> A.Change line 25 to the following code segment:
>   DuplexChannelFactory  factory = new
>   DuplexChannelFactory(callbackContext, binding,
>   address);
>
> B.Change line 26 to the following code segment:       IGreetingService
>   greetingServicefactory = CreateChannel(callbackContext);
>
> C.Add the following code segment after line 26:
>   callbackContextIncomingChannelsAdd((IDuplexChannel)greetingService)
>
> D.Add the following code segment after line 26:
>   callbackContext.OutgoingChannels.Add((IDuplexChannel)greetingService)

For this question, the answer is supposed to be `AB`. `A` I can understand but I can't find any information about a standalone `CreateChannnel` method like it's used in `B`

Can anyone explain why answer `B` is considered correct or is it **not** correct and I'm better of ditching these practice exams alltogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer B is a misprint. It should read:

```
IGreetingService greetingService = factory.CreateChannel(callbackContext);
```

Comment: Thanks, that would explain a lot but it's also symptomatic about the quality of this practice exam.